# Replacing tokens inside string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, replace, c++17

What i am trying to do is to replace all the tokens with a similiar syntax `[[VULKAN_SDK]]`  inside a string. I want to take the contents of the brackes(in this case `VULKAN_SDK`) and replace the entire token with a value i get from `getenv` by passing the contents of the brackets. Example  `[[VULKAN_SDK]]` gets replaced by `C:\VulkanSDK\1.2.148.1`(a system enviroment variable).
If the enviroment variable does not exist then the token should not be replaced.
Here is my code:

```
void replaceSystemEnviromentTokens(std::string& var) {
  static const char* tokenOpening = "[[";
  static const char* tokenClosure = "]]";
  auto getEnvVal = [](const char* var) { 
    char * val = std::getenv(var);
    return val == NULL ? std::string() : std::string(val);
  };
  
  std::size_t temp = var.find(tokenOpening, 0);
  while(temp != std::string::npos) {
    const std::size_t beginning = temp;
    const std::size_t end = var.find(tokenClosure, beginning);
    temp = var.find(tokenOpening, beginning + 1);
    
    if(end == std::string::npos) 
      break;
    
    if(temp != std::string::npos)
      if(end > temp)
        continue;
    
    const std::size_t tokenSize = end - (beginning + strlen(tokenOpening));
    const std::string token = var.substr(beginning + strlen(tokenOpening), tokenSize);
    const std::string translatedToken = getEnvVal(token.c_str());
    
    if(!translatedToken.empty()) {
      const std::size_t currentSize = var.length();
      var.replace(beginning, end, translatedToken);
      if(temp != std::string::npos) {
        temp += currentSize - var.length();
        if(temp > var.length())
          temp = std::string::npos;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Testing:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::string test = "this should be converted: [[VULKAN_SDK]] this should not be converted: VULKAN_SDK]] this: [[VULKAN_SDK]]";
  replaceSystemEnviromentTokens(test);
  std::cout << test << std::endl;
}
```

current behavior: `this should be converted: C:\VulkanSDK\1.2.148.1erted: VULKAN_SDK]] this: [[VULKAN_SDK]]`

expected behavior: `this should be converted: C:\VulkanSDK\1.2.148.1 this should not be converted: VULKAN_SDK]] this: C:\VulkanSDK\1.2.148.1`

Comment: Why don't you use the in-built `replace()` function in c++17?

Comment: Would there be any string such as `test = "this should be replaced [[vul[kan]]"?` What should happen in cases like these? What I am trying to ask is that would the character `'['` or `']'`appear in strings like any other normal character?

Comment: or `test = "abc [[vul[[kan]] xyz"` or `test = "abc [[[kan]] xyz"`?

Comment: Or what if `test = "abc [[vul [[jjk]] hkj [[hjh]] [[nj [[ hjgk[[ ]]ghjg[[gfgh]] ]] ]] [[kan]] xyz"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the in-built `replace()` function in C++17, you can accomplish the above stated task with minimal code.

If the given string `test = "abc [[vul [[hjh]] [[nj [[ hg[[gfgh]] ]]m ]]xyz"` or `"abc [[vul[[kan]] xyz"` or of similar type then you can see this as a variation of the [balanced parenthesis](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-for-balanced-parentheses-in-an-expression/) problem which is solved using stack.

```
void replaceSystemEnviromentTokens(std::string& var) {
    static const char* tokenOpening = "[[";
    static const char* tokenClosure = "]]";
        auto getEnvVal = [](const char* var) {
        char * val = std::getenv(var);
        return val == NULL ? std::string() : std::string(val);
    };
    std::stack<int> s;
    for(int i =0; i<var.size();i++){
        if(var[i]=='[' && (i+1)<var.size() && var[i+1]=='['){
            s.push(i);
            i++;
        }
        if(var[i]==']' && (i+1)<var.size() && var[i+1]==']'){
            if(!s.empty()){
                // This means we have encountered a [[ before as well
                // And using the stack, we would get the most recent [[
                int a = s.top();
                s.pop();
                // A corner case of [[]] can be checked here i.e empty string
                // The case of [[ ]] can also be checked but for now it is omitted
                int beg = a + strlen(tokenOpening);
                const std::size_t tokenSize = i - beg;
                if(tokenSize > 0){
                    // Non-empty token enclosed between [[____]]
                    const std::string token = var.substr(beg, tokenSize);
                    const std::string translatedToken = getEnvVal(token.c_str());
                    if(!translatedToken.empty()) {
                        var.replace(a, tokenSize + strlen(tokenOpening) + strlen(tokenClosure), translatedToken);
                        /*
                        Here you need to decide what to initialize i with here
                        If the translatedToken itself would bring more [[___]] pairs
                        and you would want to replace their tokens as well
                        then i = a-1, if not then i = a + translatedToken.size()-1
                        */
                        i = a + translatedToken.size()-1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: risingStark found that the original version wasn't working! This is a fix which looks definitely uglier than the original one, but at least it works. I really hate the need to start over with the iterator, but I couldn't quickly find a better way. Try this out here: https://ideone.com/Hcb4BM

I wanted to do it with regular expressions, but it took me forever to understand how those work in C++. Anyway, this is the result:

```
void replaceSystemEnviromentTokens(std::string& var)
{
    static std::string tokenOpening = "\\[\\[";
    static std::string tokenClosure = "\\]\\]";
    auto getEnvVal = [](const std::string& var) {
        char* val = getenv(var.c_str());
        return std::string(val ? val : "");
    };

    std::regex re(tokenOpening + "(\\S+)" + tokenClosure);
    std::sregex_iterator it(var.begin(),var.end(),re);
    std::sregex_iterator end;
    while (it != end) {
        auto& m = *it;
        auto value = getEnvVal(m.str(1));
        if (!value.empty()) {
            std::regex re_replace(tokenOpening + m.str(1) + tokenClosure);
            var = regex_replace(var, re_replace, value);
            it = std::sregex_iterator(var.begin(), var.end(), re);
        }
        else {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not so sure it's better than the accepted answer, but at least now I know how to use `<regex>`... I think there must be a better way to deal with the creation of a new regular expression for each token, but I can't see anything to solve the problem.

Comment: It is not working. Its going in an infinite loop. Did you try running it once?

Comment: @risingStark Whops, you're right! If you have a token which is not defined in the environment it will keep trying to substitute it... sigh... My test was https://ideone.com/BoG8dB. Unfortunately I missed that case.

Comment: @risingStark Check out the new version.